# Is it possible to install fabric8 platform completely offline?

Tags: linux, kubernetes, fabric8

I want to install fabric8 platform on existing kubernetes cluster completely offline.
Is it possible ?

Comment: Have you tried it out before asking?

Comment: Yes fabric8 is just docker images, so if you have a docker registry that is offline, you can install anything into kubernetes from that registry.

Comment: @bub I tried gofabric8 installer. I have no idea how to make this installer work offline.

Comment: @ClausIbsen I thought that the only way to deploy fabric8 is with gofabric8 installer. Now found that i just need docker images of fabric8-console.